# ActiveMQ transport type choice depending on the system type

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ provides a number of transport types, depending on different situations, so I made a small research over here - http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-version-5-transports.html

But I haven't found any place of what would be the best practice in the transport type choice depending on the system communication type.

Let's say I have these ways of typical communication ways:

1. There is a very high system load with small messages.
2. There is a low/average system load with big messages.
3. There is a high system load with big messages.

What would be the pluses and minuses for the most used transport types in the described ways? What would be also important to pay attention to?

These question may seem weird, but I am a bit new to the ActiveMQ. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

off the top, here is my take...

- if your client is in the same JVM as your broker, then use the VM transport because it doesn't require network communication
- if you have a large number (1000's) of client connections, then use NIO because it handles connections more efficiently
- if your clients are non Java based, then consider using STOMP
- if you need secure/encrypted messaging, then use SSL or NIO-SSL
- otherwise, for general use...just use TCP

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that.